# How to find future in Spring ThreadPoolTaskScheduler

Tags: java, spring, scheduling

I'm using Spring `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` and I need to find and cancel future by some condition.

is it right to have a `ScheduledFuture` field in `Runnable` task and collect tasks into `ArrayList`? Should I use `CopyOnWriteArrayList`?

```
class Task implements Runnable {
  public Task(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  private final int id;
  private ScheduledFuture future;
  public void setFuture(ScheduledFuture future) {
    this.future = future;
  }
  public ScheduledFuture getFuture() {
    return future;
  }
  public int getId() {
    return this.id;
  }
  public void run() {
    System.out.println(this.id);
  }
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ServiceTest {
  private final ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler;
  private final ArrayList<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
  @PostConstruct
  public void registerTasks() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      Task task = new Task(i);
      ScheduledFuture future = threadPoolTaskScheduler.schedule(task, new 
      PeriodicTrigger(100));
      task.setFuture(future);
      tasks.add(task);
    }
  }
  public void stopTask(int id) {
    Iterator<Task> it = tasks.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
      Task task = it.next();
      if (task.getId() == id) {
        task.getFuture().cancel(false);
        it.remove();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*is it right to have a ScheduledFuture field in Runnable task?*

From purely technical standpoint, I don't think there is any issue in storing a ScheduledFuture in the instance of the Task class which is implementing Runnable, because your Task class instance will just store it as state information, which you can use later in your code like you have done in the *stopTask()* method. Also, just to note here you are using a PeriodicTrigger which means the thread will keep on executing after the 100 ms time interval provided, unless the task is cancelled.

NOTE: Please ensure that your actual run() method does not change class variable future in any way. (although this is not done in the question, your real code should also not have any such changes to the future variable from inside the run() method)

*collect tasks into ArrayList? Should I use CopyOnWriteArrayList?*

There is no harm in using an ArrayList here, as you are using this out of any multi-threaded context. If this list was supposed to be used in a multi-threaded context, then you could probably think of using CopyOnWriteArrayList. To be precise, your ServiceTest class is having a registerTasks() method which is modifying/accessing your list, and this method is not being invoked in a multi-threaded manner as per the code shown in the question. So, there is no need for CopyOnWriteArrayList here.

Also, if needed, you could also check whether the task was cancelled or not using the returned boolean value from the call to cancel method. You may want to use it to do any further actions.

---

UPDATE:
Oh well, I overlooked that modification via the iterator. I agree that the *stopTask()* method could be accessed in a multi-threaded manner if it can be invoked via a REST Controller. However, CopyOnWriteArrayList does not support remove() method on its iterator() just in case you are thinking of using that. Also, using CopyOnWriteArrayList is only advisable if you have a majority of read operations than write operations on the list. It is actually meant for safe traversals where majority are read operations using the iterator. I would suggest synchronizing *stopTask()* method or using *Collections.synchronizedList(tasks)*

Comment: registerTasks() method which is modifuing task list is not being invoked in multi-threaded manner, that's right. But if stopTask() is being invoked from @RestController is it multithreaded manner? Some people can invoke it at the same time by URL .../stopTask/id

Comment: Updated answer above, as comment is too long.